# EditorTemplates - Sharing implementation between Date.cshtml and DateTime.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have an editor template for DateTime and Date.  The contents of Date is a simple copy and paste from DateTime.  That's awful copy-and-paste coding.

Is there a good way for properties decorated with `[DataType(DataType.Date)]` to use the DateTime editor template?  What about directing from the Date template to utilize the DateTime template with some added ViewData information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How much code is in your editor templates?

What I usually do is have a shared layout for all editor templates that contains most of the common HTML for my templates, and then you're left with (usually) just one line of code for the actual type-specific HTML.

For example, here is a simplified version of a layout editor template:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<p>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m):
</p>
<p>
    @RenderSection("value")
</p>
<p>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
</p>
```

Then here are a couple type-specific templates:

**String.cshtml**

```
@model System.String
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section value{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m)
}
```

**Password.cshtml**

```
@model System.String
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@section value{
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m)
}
```

Comment: Ah, great idea to encapsulate this stuff in a layout!  In truth Date and DateTime share everything, for some reason going from MVC3 to MVC5 caused properties decorated as `DataType.Date` to no longer use the DateTime template.  There is some code schenanigans to handle merging classes requested from the call to `@Html.LabelAndEditorFor()` and the standard classes I'm applying, but that's really it.

Comment: Excellent elegant solution.